# Rails Given an array of objects from a db, is there a way to get an item in the array w/o having to rehit the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given:

```
@votes (user_id, option_id)
```

If do: `@project.votes` I get all the votes for that project.

If I then want to see what the current user voted for I have to do:

```
Votes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
```

This is a record that's already in the @project votes query. Is there a way I can find the record in that first query w/o having to rehit the db?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the regular ruby [Enumerable#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001488) method:

```
@votes = project.votes.all
# ... other code ...
current_user_votes = @votes.select{ |v| v.user_id == current_user.id }
```

This will return an array of all the user's votes for the project. If the user is only allowed one vote, and you want a single value, not an array, just use `.first` like so:

```
@votes = project.votes.all
# ... other code ...
current_user_vote = @votes.select{ |v| v.user_id == current_user.id }.first
```